# Deploying uploading document as a Document set in sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, office-365, csom

I want to Upload a document in document set fields and move that document into one of the folders in Document Set not as Attachment File as a Uploading Document.